# Check if a script/style was enqueued/registered

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-style, wp-register-script, wp-enqueue-style

Is it possible to test whether a script or a style was registered using `wp_register_script/_style` or `wp_enqueue_script/_style`? All functions doesn't return a value and I'm completely clueless.

I need it to switch between different functions depending on stylesheet-libraries and scripts I offer.

Thank you!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There is a function called [`wp_script_is( $handle, $list )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_script_is/). `$list` can be one of:

- 'registered' -- was registered through `wp_register_script()`
- 'queue' -- was enqueued through `wp_enqueue_script()`
- 'done' -- has been printed
- 'to_do' -- will be printed

Ditto all that for [`wp_style_is()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_script_is/).

Answer (score 11):

Check `$GLOBALS['wp_scripts']->registered` for scripts.

**Example**

```
function is_enqueued_script( $script )
{
    return isset( $GLOBALS['wp_scripts']->registered[ $script ] );
}

print (int) is_enqueued_script( 'l10n' );
```

`$GLOBALS['wp_styles']->registered` works the same way.

Comment: Down voted this due lack of sanity checking, leaves the possibility for fatal errors.

Comment: @Backie, but you understand that this is a proof of concept?

Comment: wp_script_is() is a better and safer solution (Adam Backstrom` ) solution